# Redirecting through a variable in php

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have my link in a variable:
`$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

I am passing the `$actual_link` through sessions to another page and want there to redirect it to main page i.e `$actual_link` for a particular condition.

The `location("header:yoururl.com")` doesn't work as it requires a definite url. So anything that can serve my cause?

Comment: What's wrong with `header("location: $actual_link");` exactly? And what is a 'definite url'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap array element in {} if you put it into a string

```
$actual_link = "http://${_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}${_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
```

and a key need to be a string in single quote.

or you can put array element outside of string

```
$actual_link = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

olso if you want it to work with SSL use this check

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on"
```

and put s after http

```
$protocole = "http" . ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on" ? 's' : '');
$actual_link =  $protocole . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

then you can redirect the url using header

```
header('Location: ' . $actual_link);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$actual_link = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header( 'Location: ' . $actual_link ) ;
exit;
```

Include `''` in `HTTP_HOST` and `REQUEST_URI`

Answer (score 0):

use `header( 'Location: ' . $actual_link );`

If you are meaning this, please explain what's not working - and show your code on the try.